# Wrong image file path obtained from Android file manager

Tags: android, android-intent, android-imageview, android-image, android-file

In my application I would like to open an image and "load" it to the app using File Manager. I've already doneit using `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` and `onActivityResult()` method. Everything works fine, except from the path which I get. It is in a strange format and I can't show the image in `ImageView`

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            mFileManagerString = selectedImageUri.getPath();
            showPreviewDialog(mFileManagerString);
        }
}
```

Here `mFileManagerString = /document/image:19552`

When I call a method to show the image in the `ImageView`:

```
public void setPreviewIV(String pPath) {
        Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pPath);
        receiptPreviewIV.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/image:19552: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

How to get the proper path to the image, so that I can show it in the `ImageView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to get the proper path to the image

You already have it. It is the `Uri` that is passed into `onActivityResult()` via the `Intent` parameter. Pulling just `getPath()` out of that `Uri` is pointless. That's akin to thinking that `/questions/33827687/wrong-image-file-path-obtained-from-android-file-manager` is a path on your hard drive, just because your Web browser shows a URL that contains that path.

In addition, your current code is loading and decoding the `Bitmap` on the main application thread. Do not do this, because it freezes the UI while that work is being done.

I recommend that you use any one of the many [image-loading libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/46). All the decent ones (e.g., Picasso, Universal Image Loader) not only take a `Uri` as input but also will load the image on a background thread for you, applying it to your `ImageView` on the main application thread only when the bitmap is ready.

If, for whatever reason, you feel that you have to do this yourself, use `ContentResolver` and its `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` for the data represented by the `Uri`. Then, pass that to `decodeStream()` on `BitmapFactory`. Do all of that in a background thread (e.g., `doInBackground()` of an `AsyncTask`), and then apply the `Bitmap` to the `ImageView` on the main application thread (e.g., `onPostExecute()` of an `AsyncTask`).